# Как подключить новую Стратегию в passport

Tags: node.js, cookie, mongoose, passport

Есть код, все что он делает - проверяет правильность username и password

Если оба критерия введены верно, нас перекидывает на admin.html, если же нет, мы остаемся на login.html, этот код (Стратегия) только для админ страницы проекта, хочу еще сделать стратегию с куками на пользователей, как это правильно сделать? Имею ввиду как подключить вторую стратегию, чтоб они (и первая и вторая) между собой не конфликтовали!? Причем во второй стратегии хочу проверять на login и password.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var Admin = require('./models/admin');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
 app.use(cookieParser());

var session = require('cookie-session');
app.use(session({keys:['secret'],maxAge: 2*60*60*1000}));

var passport = require('passport');
app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session()); 

var localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
passport.use(new localStrategy(function(username,password,done){
    Admin.find({username: username, password: password},function(err,data){
            if(data.length == 1){
                return done(null,{id: data[0]._id});
            }
            else{
                return done(null,false);
            }
        });
}));
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null,user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id,done){
    Admin.find({_id: id},function(err,data){
            done(null,{username:data[0].username, id: data[0]._id}); 
        });
});

var auth = passport.authenticate('local',{
        successRedirect: '/admin',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
});
var myAuth = function(req,res,next){

    if(req.isAuthenticated())
        next();
    else
        res.redirect('/login');
}
app.post('/login',auth);
app.get('/admin',myAuth);

app.get('/login',function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/viewAdmin/login.html');
});
app.get('/admin',function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/viewAdmin/admin.html');
});
```

Comment: У вас есть функция myAuth, которая проверяет авотризирован ли пользователь. Напишите функцию adminOnly, которая будет проверять если пользователь является администратором, то выдавать ему страницу, а если нет, то перекидывать на главную (или любую другую) страницу.

Comment: Спасибо, хоть уже разобрался (через стратегию facebook добавив новую модель), но Вашу версию испробую на новом проекте.